# Push the second div below on increase in height of first div

Tags: css, sass

I am making accordion buttons and its div wrapped in a div container. I want to keep them in grid of 2 columns. Like below,

[image]

But when I open one of them the below divs should push down. I tried using both `display:grid` and `display:flex` but it does not get pushed. It goes behind the second accordion button. How do I push? I just need an idea. Not exact code.

[image]

Comment: share your code to understand the issue

Comment: without sufficient code, It is hard to know what exactly do you want?

Comment: I don't want exact code. I just want to discuss how you would achieve something like this?

Answer (score 1):

You would need to expand the dropdown. I think what happens is the dropdown displays on top of of other dropdowns, so the other dropdowns do not get pushed down.

Here is the code for it

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
.collapsible {
    background-color: grey;
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 18px;
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
    text-align: left;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 15px;
}


.content {
    padding: 0 18px;
    display: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: white;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<button type="button" class="collapsible">Dropdown 1</button>
<div class="content">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
</div>
<button type="button" class="collapsible">Dropdown 2</button>
<div class="content">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
</div>
<button type="button" class="collapsible">Dropdown 3</button>
<div class="content">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
</div>

<script>
    let coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");
    let i;

    for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
        coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
            let content = this.nextElementSibling;
            if (content.style.display === "block") {
            content.style.display = "none";
            } else {
            content.style.display = "block";
            }
        });
    }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Here the `content` has a display of `none`. When it is clicked, the `content` will have a display of `block`.
Javascript will check when the button is clicked, if `content` has a display of block, it will change it to `none` and vice versa.

I hope you understood my code.
Try checking out [this link](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_collapsible.asp) from w3schools for more detail. There is also a section available for animated dropdowns and adding icons.